# Java: Data type similar to javascript object?

Tags: java, javascript, android

In java, is there any data type similar to javascript object type where I can store stuff something like we do in javascript.

Here is an object and it contains three arrays inside:

```
var myObject = {"smsBody": [], "totalSMS": [], "sender": []};
```

I can push data to **individual array items** inside that object:

```
myObject.totalSMS.push("5");
myObject.totalSMS.push("10");
```

And then can **loop over them** to get whole data out of an array item:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myObject.totalSMS.length; i++) {
  alert(myObject.totalSMS[i]);
}
```

Is there something similar in Java plz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is about as close as you can get in Java to the code you posted:

```
Map<String, List<String>> myObject = new HashMap<>();
myObject.put("smsBody", new ArrayList<>());
myObject.put("totalSMS", new ArrayList<>());
myObject.put("sender", new ArrayList<>());

List<String> totalSMS = myObject.get("totalSMS");
totalSMS.add("5");
totalSMS.add("10");

for (String s : totalSMS) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Note there are quite a few little differences, like the fact that you cannot use something like `myObject.totalSMS`, but rather need to use the String `"totalSMS"` as the key of a Map. Java also has a more convenient for-each loop, which means you don't need to iterate over the indices of the elements and access them separately (although you can still loop over a list by the element indices if you want).

Answer (score 1):

What you have described can be described as an array of arrays in java. You could use a collection such as [ArrayList](http://www.examiner.com/article/a-simple-java-arraylist-example) to make it more dynamic. If you are looking for something more general to store different types of elements, you should consider using an [inner class](http://www.learn-java-tutorial.com/inner-classes.cfm).

To refer to your example, the code in JAVA would be (providing all of the arrays contain only integers):

```
 ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> myObject = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    myObject.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
    myObject.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
    myObject.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());

    myObject.get(0).add(5);
    myObject.get(0).add(10);

    for (Integer i : myObject.get(0))
     System.out.println(i);
```

If you would like to name the Collections you could use an Map:

```
 Map<String,ArrayList<Integer>> myObject = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<Integer>>();
    myObject.put("smsBody",new ArrayList<Integer>());
    myObject.put("totalSms",new ArrayList<Integer>());
    myObject.put("sender",new ArrayList<Integer>());

    myObject.get("totalSms").add(5);
    myObject.get("totalSms").add(10);

    for (Integer i : myObject.get("totalSms"))
     System.out.println(i);
```